# Failed to execute MAVEN goal using netbeans 7.3.1, JDK 7x64 does not work on Win 8 64-bit

Tags: java, window, 64-bit, maven-3, netbeans-7

I'm new and I'm starting with maven using NETBEANS now install 7.3.1, JDK 7x64, I formatted my Win 8 64-bit machine now I have problems with NETBEANS or MAVEN've tried everything, create the variables JAVA_HOME, I installed maven NETBEANS matter and I have the same error.
I've used VirtualBox with Win Xp and perfect running Maven, I have no connection error not use proxy, but in Win 8 does not work, I turned off antivirus, Firewall

```
mvn.bat -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6 -DarchetypeVersion=1.5 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=mavenproject1 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.mycompany.mavenproject1 -Dbasedir=C:\\Users\\jaime\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode archetype:generate -X -e
```

> ```
> Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar
> ```
>
> Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar
>   [DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\jaime.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\1.8.3\groovy-1.8.3.jar.lastUpdated
>   [DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\jaime.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.8.1\ant-1.8.1.jar.lastUpdated

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar from central failed: Connection reset -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues and never tracked down the exact problem, but somewhere along the line, reinstalling Java sets it right.